# Deleting a dynamically added div on a parent causes it to append again

Tags: javascript, jquery

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daL6s/3/)

I am trying to dynamically add a div on clicking `td.active`. I wish to remove the dynamically added div when someone click on the close button or click on other `td.active`

Right now my code just append another div when the close button is clicked. can anyone help me to fix the issue.

```
$(function() {
    $('td.active').click(function(event){
        $(this).append('<div class="planner-modal"><div class="planner-modal-header"><button type="button" class="close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button><h5 class="text-center">modal heading</h5></div><div class="planner-modal-body">modal body</div><div class="caret-container"><div class="top-caret"></div><div class="bottom-caret"></div></div></div>');
    });
    $('.planner-modal-header.close').click(function(e){
        $(this).closest('planner-modal').remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: I think you forget to put dot "." at closest('planner-modal'). Try closest('.planner-modal')

Comment: @exculuber Thanks. tried that. did not work either.

Comment: put the $('.planner-modal-header.close').click(function(e){
        $(this).closest('.planner-modal').remove();
    }); inside the td.active click function

Comment: did not work. http://jsfiddle.net/daL6s/12/

Answer (score 2):

I have gone through the jsfiddle and fixed it. you were trying to call click event on dynamically added content for ding this we can use jQuery on method.
i am sharing the jsfiddle link.

```
  $(document).on("click",'.close',function(e){

      $('.planner-modal').remove()
    });
```

[click here to see the working jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/daL6s/13/)

thanks

Comment: If only one planner-modal should be open at the same time this could work. However, you should insert $('.planner-modal').remove() to the begining of td.active click function

Comment: i think i have done that in the click function of td.active go through the jsfiddle link..:) thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use event delegation for dynamicaly created element

```
  $('td.active').on("click", ".planner-modal-header .close", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); 
    $(this).closest('.planner-modal').remove();
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/daL6s/17/)

use `e.stopPropagation();`  to stop the [bubbling event](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

Comment: @Bala can you see my fiddle and fix it

Comment: @Bala i think u have forgot to mention e.stopPropagation()

Comment: @user2847429 now check demo